# How to edit the layers defined when initializing a Editor?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am having some problems with editing the Editor object. We have multiple layers that are editable by the user, and the user can enable and disable layers. When a layer is disable/enabled the Editor object should be modified or removed+created to make sure the layers are visible in the toolbar.

We have this method for creating the editor, but how could I modify the layers inside the editor (or templatepicker), when the object is allready initialized..

```
            this.addToolbar = function(map, id, layers, featureLayers) {
                if (dijit.byId(id)) {                        
                    //TODO Update existing editor if layers changed
                } else {
                    var settings = {
                        map: map,
                        layerInfos: featureLayers,
                        createOptions: {

                            polylineDrawTools: [Editor.CREATE_TOOL_FREEHAND_POLYLINE],
                            polygonDrawTools: [Editor.CREATE_TOOL_FREEHAND_POLYGON,
                                Editor.CREATE_TOOL_CIRCLE,
                                Editor.CREATE_TOOL_TRIANGLE,
                                Editor.CREATE_TOOL_RECTANGLE
                            ]
                        },

                        toolbarVisible: false,
                        toolbarOptions: {
                            reshapeVisible: true
                        }
                    };
                    var params = {
                        settings: settings
                    };
                    var myEditor = new Editor(params, id);
                    myEditor.startup();
                }
            }
```

So i could store the value of myEditor, but what variable do I change, and how do I make sure it updates the html?
Any ideas?

**Update**:
This is not the way to go, when i destroy a editor, the elements that are already drawn with it are not editable anymore. I will just show and hide the editors with some plain js.

Answer (score 1):

Nest your editor node in another container.

```
<div id="editorContainer">
  <div id="editor"> </div>
</div>
```

Move the settings and params before the if statement.

Then in the TODO part -

1. destroy the editor

   myEditor.destroyRecursive();
2. recreate the editor div in the editorContainer

   domConstruct.create("div",{id:"editor"},"editorContainer");
3. recreate the editor

   var myEditor = new Editor(params, id);

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I found out that elements that are drawn with a toolbar are not editable anymore when that toolbar is re-created.. So i need to change the way the app works atm.